# Get largest Map from an RDD of Array of Maps

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I have an Array of Maps in an RDD like this:

```
Map("id" -> 1, "name" -> "punit")
Map("id" -> 2, "name" -> "naik", "ph_no" -> 123123)
```

Now my aim is to write this Array of maps to a CSV file which will look like this:

```
id,ph_no,name
1,,punit
2,123123,naik
```

The ID 1 has not provided a ph_no and that's why it is empty in the CSV. So I want to traverse through this RDD and find the Map with the largest size so that I can name all the fields in the header by extracting it's keys.

In scala terms it would be:

```
val x = Array(Map("id" -> 1, "name" -> "punit"),Map("id" -> 2, "name" -> "naik", "ph_no" -> 123123)).maxBy(_.size)
```

which will correctly give me:

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(id -> 2, name -> naik, ph_no -> 123123)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for the max sized `Map` element might not be accurate enough as maybe none of them have all the data (judging from the example). 
You could obtain the list of headers by doing an union of all distinct keys in the maps. 
Something like:

```
val rddOfMaps:RDD[Map[String,Any]] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map("a"->1, "b"->2, "d"->3),Map("a"->2, "c"->4, "e" -> 1)))
val headers = rddOfMaps.flatMap(entry => entry.keySet).distinct.collect
val csvData = rddOfMaps.map(entry => header.map(column => entry.get(column).getOrElse("")).mkString(","))

// 1,2,,3,
// 2,,4,,1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.max()`, specifying an ordering by the size of the map.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(Map("id" -> 1, "name" -> "punit"),Map("id" -> 2, "name" -> "naik", "ph_no" -> 123123)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val maxMap = rdd.max()(Ordering.by(_.size))
maxMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(id -> 2, name -> naik, ph_no -> 123123)
```

By the way since you are working with CSV files, you might be interested by using `spark-csv`.